# How to check if many queries results are successful

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to check if all queries (say 8) of one page are successful ?

Comment: Some context on why you need this and what you have tried (and why that doesn't work) would help. As it is the question IMO is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this.

```
$mysqli= new mysqli(db-host,db-user,db-pass,db-name);
$query="select * from abc"; 
$result=$mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

similiar for all queries

```
$query1="...";
$$result2=...;
if($result && $result2) 
{ echo "successful"; }
```